# Unable to use application_ruby cookbook with Chef 11.8.0, Cannot find a resource for bundle_options

Tags: ruby, bundler, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have been attempting to setup a chef recipe which installs ruby using RVM and then uses the application_ruby cookbook to configure the application, however I keep running into the error

```
NameError: Cannot find a resource for bundle_options on ubuntu version 12.04
```

I am using the following code

```
application "application setup" do
  owner "ubuntu"
  group "ubuntu"
  repository "https://github.com/me/myapplication.git" // Real address removed
  path rails_app_path
  revision "master"

  rails do
    bundler true
    precompile_assets true
    bundler_deployment true
  end
end
```

I noticed that the bundle_options was recently added, https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_ruby/commit/e7719170a661a957796e8e5d58ba8f4ecd937487 however I am unable to track down if this is causing the issue. I have included

```
depends          "application"
depends          "application_ruby"
```

in my metadata.rb and made sure all my dependencies are installed so I am unsure what I am doing wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation **bundle_options** is an **attribute** of the rails resource, not a resource itself. 
The only correct way of using it is **INSIDE** the "**rails**" block, so you got the message because you either used it as :

- an attribute of the application resource (but outside of the "rails" block)
- standalone resource (outside of any resource).

Message you mentioned is being displayed when nonexistent resource is being referenced. e.g. if you had tried to execute following code on your system:

```ruby
 nonexistent_resource "failure gonna happen" do
     some_attribute "whatever_value"
 end
```

you would've got a message

> NameError: Cannot find a resource for **nonexistent_resource** on Ubuntu version 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today as well. It appears the problem is that commit e771917 forgot to add the necessary getter for the bundle_option. Someone filed a PR to fix it (https://github.com/poise/application_ruby/pull/44), but it has not yet been merged. I can confirm that when I made that change locally, this error went away. The forked branch in the PR is located at https://github.com/mauriciosilva/application_ruby/tree/bundle_options_fix.